# Creating fat (uber) aar on Android with grade

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I have android project with 2 modules:
* Library that should be published.
* Another library used internally by the first library (dependency).

I need to generate "aar" file that contains the code for both libraries like in a fat (uber) jar.
Of course most of the code is obscured with proguard.

I tried several gradle plugins that doesn't work.

Is there any decent solution for this issue?

Comment: Your question is too vague - what plugins did you try and what exactly was not working?